# Discord.py Cogs/Tasks API: Why Do I have to manually start tasks after starting them in my __init__ function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, scheduled-tasks

I've been stuck trying to get scheduled tasks for a discord bot I want to build up and running. Incase my scheduling was causing issues I decided to just do the timed task because has less outside variables that could be effecting a task running.

From other examples I've seen and the documentation the `self.printer.start()` should start the operation in the init function? The Below code "works" but I would like to know why the `self.printer.start()` methods don't start until started manually by the bot.

MyCog.py

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from times import times

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        print("cog added")
        self.bot = bot
        bot.printer = self.printer
        self.index = 0
        self.printer.start()
        print("end init")

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def printer(self):
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

test.py

```py
import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio
from TOKEN import TOKEN
from MyCog import MyCog
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')
    if not bot.printer.is_running():
        bot.printer.start()
    #bot.MyCog.start()

async def main():
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot=bot))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

python 3.10.4 running on Windows 10

Comment: Why not? Maybe someone wants to start a task when something happens... It's just the design of the library.

Comment: I don't think you have an understanding of the question here, I call .start() in the __init__  and discords docs imply that that it's possible to start a task in a cog that way.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html
but I still have to manually start tasks. 
are the docs outdated and you can't do that? am I calling/adding the cog wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not occur in my bots. I believe it is related to the way you are starting your bot. When you use `asyncio.run(main())`, a new loop is created and automatically destroyed when the given function completes (which implies the cancellation of all created tasks). I recommend you start your bot as follows:

```py
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot=bot))
        await bot.start(TOKEN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This way, the `main()` function will only end when the bot is stopped running and the tasks you created when adding the cog will be permanent.